# Why is the queue lost if I don't set the pool option in celery in python?

Tags: python, queue, celery

I am simply setting up and using celery in python. But the celery queue seems to be getting lost, so I'm checking it.

For example, if there is a process that finishes `task A` and sends a queue to `task B`, the data in `A` and `B` should match, but it often doesn't match.

It was probably lost in the process of queue being delivered to the celery `task B`.

When I set the `'--pool=solo'` option, nothing was lost, but the processing speed seems to be slow.

Previously, no options related to `'pool'` were set.

May I know what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please tell us what you use as Celery broker. The description of the problem is unclear. You do not send queue to a task - you send a task to the queue.